# warning variable unused in assert

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework, assert

I can test the content after a redirection like this

```
assert "/url" = redir_path = redirected_to(conn, 302)
conn = get(recycle(conn), redir_path)
assert html_response(conn, 200) ==  "Content after redirection"
```

But I cannot add a param variable to the assert url like this:

```
id = 10
assert "/url/#{id}" = redir_path = redirected_to(conn, 302)
```

It complains with:

> cannot invoke remote function id/0 inside match

So if I just define the path like this before using it:

```
url_path = "/url/%{id}"
assert url_path = redir_path = redirected_to(conn, 302)
```

> warning: variable "url_path" is unused

?? unusued? is it being used inside the assert...

Not sure how to silence that warning or how to approach this.

The code is similar to Chris's response here:

https://elixirforum.com/t/following-redirection-in-controllertests/10084

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > warning: variable "url_path" is unused
>
> ?? unusued? is it being used inside the assert...

No, it's not. Your assert will match any value because if you have a variable name on the LHS of a match, it matches any value and that variable gets assigned the value of the RHS.

In:

```
foo = 10
assert foo = 20
IO.inspect foo
```

the assert passes and `foo` is printed as `20`.

If you just want to assert that that string equals the value returned by `redirected_to/2`, you can use `==`:

```
assert "/url/#{id}" == redirected_to(conn, 302)
```

Comment: Just as an addition, to prevent rebounding one might pin the variable: `foo = 10 and assert_raise ^foo = 20`. [The pin operator](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html#the-pin-operator).